# jqGrid with Bootstrap. jqGrid doesn't load the data. It has error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I used jqGrid and jQueryUI. It works well
this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8-amh6qxsPSazExNjR1TkNIbzA/view

And I changed the scripts folder which has jQueryUI to jQuery-BootStrap with jqGrid
http://jquery-ui-bootstrap.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/extra.html?repeat=on#jqgrid

It doesn't work as I changed the folder and the error is at this

[image]

I just changed it and I can't understand that error. It comes normally when the data-type is mismatched isn't it?

The loading doesn't end.

Please help me

`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.theme.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- jqGrid-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/third-party/jqGrid/jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/third-party/jqGrid/jqGrid.overrides.css">
    <!-- end jqGrid -->

<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/assets/js/vendor/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/assets/js/vendor/holder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/assets/js/vendor/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--jqGrid-->
<script src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/third-party/jqGrid/jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/third-party/jqGrid/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--end jqGrid-->



<!-- DOM CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/jqListFormCss.css" type="text/css" />
<style>
.ui-dialog.alert-dialog {
    font-size: 1em;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        selectedRowId="notSelected";
        createTableFunc();
    });
    function createTableFunc(){
        $("#grid").jqGrid({
            url : "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/member/listAction.do",
            datatype : "json",
            jsonReader : {
                page : "page",
                root : "list",
                total : "total"
            },
            colNames : ["id", "pw", "address", "tel"],
            colModel : [{
                name : "id", width : 50, label : "test", align : "center", editable : false
            }, {
                name : "pw", width : 50,  label : "test", align : "center", editable : true
            }, {
                name : "address", width : 50,  label : "test", align : "center", editable : true
            }, {
                name : "tel", width : 50,  label : "test", align : "center", editable : true
            }],
            width : 1000,
            height : 500,
            viewrecords : true, // View 1 - 10 of 10
            rowList : [10, 20, 30],
            caption : "Member List",
            pager : "#pager", // 페이지,
            rowNum : 20,
            multiselect: true,
            onSelectRow : function(id){ selectedRowId=id },
        }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    }

</head>
<body id="bodyTag">

    <table id="grid"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Which format have the JSON data returned from the server? It would be good if you append your question with an example of JSON data returned from `/member/listAction.do`. One can see in pictures that you use **very old 4.4.4 version of jqGrid**. Why? By the way I recommend always use non-minimized version `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` in case of error. It help to localize the problem of the error.  Do you really need to use it or you can update to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.9.2 or at least to jqGrid 4.6?

Comment: jqGrid 4.4.4 is really old. It don't contain the detection of input format. Probably you need just modify `jsonReader` and include `repeatitems: false` property. I recommend you just try to replace URLs to all jqGrid files to URLs from CDN (like it's described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). If jqGrid will display the content, that you have sure the problem with JSON format.

Comment: Thank you!!!! The reason of which the version of jqGrid is 4.4.4 is distributor include that version. Anyway I switched jqGrid to version 5.0 as just you said, it works dramatically. jqGrid 4.4.4 can't read jsonObject. It is good tip

Comment: You are welcome! By choosing of jqGrid version you should be clear which licence you need. Old jqGrid (<=4.7) can be used under MIT licence. After that you can use either [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) in current version number 5.0 or [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) in current version 4.9.2. Free jqGrid is the fork, based on 4.7 which I develop. jqGrid 5.0 is **Guriddo jqGrid JS**. You should use it only you are ready use it under its licence agreement.

Comment: My god. You are Oleg, the developer of jqGrid. It is a great pleasure.Thank you for develping great plugin. I'm studying student and I want to be programmer as you. haha